# error expected unqualified-id before '{' token

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  int pradinis = 7; 
  int tarpinis = pradinis + pradinis % 50;
  int galutinis = tarpinis / (tarpinis + 30);
  cout >>int galutinis<< endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I want to print `galutinis`. What is the problem in my code?

Comment: `cout << galutinis << endl;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote `>>` instead of `<<` in the `cout`. Plus when you want to `cout` an `integer` you do not need to put `int` before it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  int pradinis = 7; 
  int tarpinis = pradinis + pradinis % 50;
  int galutinis = tarpinis / (tarpinis + 30);
  cout << galutinis << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Improve `cout >>int galutinis<< endl;` to `cout <<galutinis<< endl;`

cout is declared as below .

```
extern ostream cout;
```

As an object of class ostream, characters can be written to it either as formatted data using the insertion operator (operator<<) or as unformatted data, using member functions such as write.